# Regex select specific characters between double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to extract specific character i.e. `;` that are located between quotes (`"`) with a Regex expression.

String example :

> Lorem;ipsum;"dolor;sit;";amet;

Should select every `;` in quotes :

> Lorem;ipsum;"dolor`;`sit`;`";amet;

I tried this one but it doesn't work

```
(?<=\")(;)*(?=\")
```

Any idea ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you guarantee there will be (at most) one pair of quotes in a given string? If there is any possibility of more than one pair of quotes, the expression will no longer be a "regular" pattern, and a code loop will be required to examine the string as a list of tokens.

Comment: Yes, it's a .csv file that has many columns with quotes. For performance reasons I would like to avoid loops

Comment: @Sufhal note that regex also perform a lot of loops in its core mechanics, you might achieve better optimisation with one more loop, and also have better readability when it comes to code quality

Comment: What if you have `"test;test"test;test"`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do it in two steps:

1. select every parts between quotes: `/"[^"]+"/gm`
2. in these matchs, search for `;`

you should be able to use `String.prototype.replace` with the given regex and look for ";" in your replace callback.

here is a demo:

```js
function escapeCsvDelimiter(input) {
  return input.replace(/"[^"]+"/gm, (match) => match.replace(/;/g, '\\;'));
}

const test = 'Lorem;ipsum;"dolor;sit;";amet;"jhv;"';
const result = escapeCsvDelimiter(test);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: There is no way to do it with only one regex ?

Comment: wouldn't be reliable imho

Comment: I'm going to run this server-side

Comment: this doesn't matter much here. If you want to improve performance that much you can precompile each regex. But as a general rule also remember that "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil"

Comment: This answer is the only way you will be able to do this with a regular expression. (There is no reasonable way to avoid loops. Another way, and maybe better if performance is of concern, just have a single loop that checks each character, counts quotes, and takes note of the `;` character when it the quote count is odd (when inside a pair of quotes).